# Spring Security and Angular token based login success but subsequent requests fails with 401

Tags: angularjs, spring, angular, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing an Angular application with a Spring based REST backend. Now I have the following issue.

I can login and get the Token from my angular application without an issue. But subsequent requests fail with 401 error. When I try the same rest endpoint in Postman with the token obtained from angular login component, it works fine.

I'm using HttpSessionStrategy, not OAuth, JWT.

I suspect some issue in my spring security config though I cannot figure it out. Could you please help me resolve this issue.

Following is the relevant part of my Spring security config.

```
@Bean
public SessionRepository<ExpiringSession> sessionRepository() {
    return new MapSessionRepository();
}

@Bean
public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
    HeaderHttpSessionStrategy strategy = new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
    strategy.setHeaderName(headerName);
    return strategy;
}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "HEAD"));
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "OPERATOR")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint())
            .and().cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
            .and().csrf().disable()
            .formLogin()
            .successHandler(new RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler(objectMapper, userDetailService))
            .failureHandler(new RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler());
}
```

And, following is the failed request and response headers of my Angular application.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the wildcard value `(*)` for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, enumerate the allowed headers:

```
configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
```

From the Docs:

> ## Access-Control-Allow-Headers
>
> ### Compatibility notes
>
> The wildcard value (*) that is mentioned in the latest specification, is not yet implemented in browsers:
>
> - Chromium: Issue 615313
> - Firefox: bug 1309358
> - Servo: Issue 13283
>
> [— MDN HTTP Reference (Access-Control-Allow-Headers)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers)